# how to convert from ArrayList<CharSequence> to CharSequence

Tags: android, arraylist

I have the following statement

```
'ArrayList<CharSequence> veg = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.vegs)));'
```

How to convert it back?

Comment: So, you want to convert an ArrayList into an array? (and not a CharSequence)?

Comment: Yest to required: CharSequence

Comment: Could you please be more specific. How it will look in my statement. I am a new one.

Comment: I am probably stupid, but here is what I have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ArrayList.toArray()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray%28T%5b%5d%29) is probably what you are looking for.

Try this:

```
    ArrayList<CharSequence> veg = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.vegs)));
    CharSequence[] vegs = new CharSequence[veg.size()]
    veg.toArray(vegs);
```

Comment: 'ArrayList<CharSequence> vegetables; vegetables = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.vegetables))); CharSequence[] vegies; vegies = new CharSequence[vegetables.size()]; vegetables.toArray(vegies);' when debugging says required: CharSequence
  found: CharSequence[] may be I am invoking incorrect method adapter.remove(vegies);

Comment: ArrayList<CharSequence> vegetables; vegetables = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.vegetables))); CharSequence[] vegies; vegies = new CharSequence[vegetables.size()]; vegetables.toArray(vegies);' when debugging says required: CharSequence found: CharSequence[] may be I am invoking incorrect method adapter.remove(vegies);

Comment: If "adapter" is an ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>, the remove method takes a CharSequence as parameter, not an array of CharSequence